# ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, please check the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer

Tags: deprecated, tf.keras, valueerror

While running this code and error is being encountered

#Predictions For First Junction

```
PredJ1 = GRU_model(X_train_Junction1,y_train_Junction1,X_test_Junction1)  

Compile model
 model.compile(optimizer=SGD(decay=1e-7, momentum=0.9),loss='mean_squared_error')  
    model.fit(X_Train,y_Train, epochs=50, batch_size=150,callbacks=[early_stopping])  
    pred_GRU= model.predict(X_Test)  
    return pred_GRU
```

```
ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, please check the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer
```